# Test Drop Table Without Actually Dropping

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

On PostgreSQL, is there an easy way to test a DDL command, specifically "drop table" without actually dropping it?

What I'd like to see are the error messages telling me I can't drop it because there view and/or inherited tables associated with it:

```
ERROR: cannot drop table sms.transfer because other objects depend on it
  Detail: view loaners.ci_all_packages_1year_snapshot depends on table sms.transfer
view loaners.whse_whse_trending depends on table sms.transfer
view loaners.ec_cases depends on table sms.transfer
view sms_write.transfer depends on table sms.transfer
table table_partitions.transfer_2012_q1 depends on table sms.transfer
table table_partitions.transfer_2012_q2 depends on table sms.transfer
table table_partitions.transfer_2012_q3 depends on table sms.transfer
table table_partitions.transfer_2012_q4 depends on table sms.transfer
```

The problem being, of course, that if there are no dependencies that would short-circuit the drop, it's actually going to drop it...  and while I want to do that *eventually*, at this point in the process I'm not ready to do that.

For a SQL query, I often hijack `explain` just to see if the code compiles without running it and was wondering (hoping) there was some way of doing this for the drop.

Comment: You can always put it into a transaction: `begin transaction; drop table foobar; rollback;`

Comment: That's perfect; thank you.  I didn't realize transactions worked for DDL.  I thought they were only for DML.